# Когда лучше использовать классовый компонент и когда лучше использовать функциональный компонент?

Tags: reactjs

Я новичок, чтобы реагировать. Когда я иду на собеседование, меня спрашивают, Когда лучше использовать классовый компонент и когда лучше использовать функциональный компонент ?. Я не знаю ответа на этот вопрос. Я знаю разницу между ними. Как лучше всего ответить на этот вопрос?

Answer (score 4):

React до версии 16.8:

- Классовый компонент - когда необходимо работать с состоянием и использовать методы жизненного цикла компонента;
- Функциональный компонент - когда компонент не использует состояние и нужно только "отрендерить" в зависимости от поступивших `props`;

React с версии 16.8:

- Классовый компонент - если не используете хуки;
- Функциональный компонент - во всех остальных случаях;

Answer (score 0):

Kомпоненты-классы нужно использовать для создания error boundaries и при ssr. В остальных случаях компонент-функция будет короче и проще.